# Set Height Parameters for Android Webview

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I try to make specific web pages fit my android webview. Some read the screen size by using javascript's screen object (screen.width).
The webview delivers the devices Display Properties which i would rather set myself.

I am also searching for a way to modify the window.innerHeight and width.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

this fixes size based on screen size

Comment: hi, thanks - this helped a bit. But is it not possible to change the screen dimension values ?